# What is this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, generating-functions, stirling-numbers, bernoulli-numbers

The sequence is:$$ a_n=\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1) {n\brack {k+2}}\;B_k\  n^k$$
$B_k$ is the Bernoulli number. ${n\brack {k}}\;$ is the unsigned Stirling number of first kind,  $\left( {0\brack {0}}\;=1 \text{  and  }{{n}\brack {k}}\;=(n-1){{n-1}\brack {k}}\;+{{n-1}\brack {k-1}}\;\right)$.

From $n=0$, the first terms  are:  $ \ \ 0\ ,\ 0\ ,\ 1\ ,\ 0\ ,\ -5\ ,\ 0\ ,\ 238\ ,\ 0\ ,\ -51508\ ,\ 0\ ,\ 35028576\ , ..$

They seem to be all integers, and the odd-indexed seem to vanish.  The generating function should be even, but I could not find it. 
Any possible combinatorial interpretation (when removing the sign)?

EDIT(i):
I have now a proof that these numbers are integers.

EDIT(ii):
I don't know for what these numbers would be relevant, nor whether they are of any importance in mathematics.  I stumbled on them while playing with an extended congruence modulo arbitrary high powers of an odd prime $p$ for the generalized Harmonic numbers $H^{(j)}_{p-1}$ $\ $ $\big(H^{(m)}_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j^m} \big)$, involving  the Bernoulli numbers $B_j$.   (I have a proof for it):  \begin{align*}\sum_{j=0}^{n}B_j H^{(j+1)}_{p-1}(-p)^j& \equiv 0  \pmod{p^{n+1}}  \end{align*}
I was curious to see what would happen with $$G^{(j+1)}_{p-1}=\sum_{1\le i_1< i_2<...<i_{j+1}\le p-1}\frac{1}{i_1\cdot i_2\cdot \cdot \cdot i_{j+1}}= \frac{{p\brack {j+2}}}{(p-1)!}$$ instead of $$ H^{(j+1)}_{p-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{i^{j+1}}$$  since it is known that the $H^{(m)}_{n}$ and $G^{(m)}_{n}$ are interelated (there is a recurrence relation involving both kinds of numbers).   Then using the first instances of this recurrence, I was able to guess - but not to prove :-(  that $$\sum_{j\ge0}(j+1)B_j G^{(j+1)}_{p-1}p^j=0 $$
And then, while checking numerically, I found out, to my surprise, that $p$ prime was not needed, and that this was apparently (numerically) true under the less restrictive condition that $p$ be odd.

Comment: Bad news, OEIS doesn't know it. https://oeis.org/search?q=0+%2C+0+%2C+1+%2C+0+%2C+-5+%2C+0+%2C+238+%2C+0+%2C+-51508+%2C+0+%2C+35028576+&sort=&language=&go=Search

Comment: All the terms in the sum are positive ... have you missed a $(-1)^k$ factor ? ... I am guessing the generating function will have zero radius of convergence ... could we divide by some factorials ?

Comment: The non-zero Bernoulli numbers alternate in sign.

Comment: @Yves, OP has since put it up on OEIS, http://oeis.org/A286483

Comment: Not a good idea to silently turn the question into an answer.

Comment: @Yves, I put it on OEIS after you told me it was not there, because I thought this would advertise it, and maybe provide an answer.

Comment: @RenéGy: no you only gave the numbers in the first version.

Comment: @Yves, sorry about anything I may have done wrong.  It might be because it took me several edits to formulate my question, and you commented on it even before I was finished.

Comment: How did you come by it; what is it relevant to?

Comment: @Robert:  see how I edited the original question in order to try to answer your questions.